# How much does a JS listener affect load times?

Tags: javascript, performance

On a site we have pixel.js and it does some visitor tracking for us. I ran a timeline and noticed all of this yellow:

[image: Listener screenshot]

According to the timeline it runs for about 4000 ms, but the aggregated time says 1218 ms for the JS. My question is, does this look troublesome?

Comment: Is it troublesome? I'd say so. [I can essentially recreate that graph here](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lkrcu7g/) and it definitely feels slower than I would expect a page to be.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, no, it isn't troublesome. In aswer to your title, it's not a lot, under 1/2 a second, depending on how many you have. Personally I always use the element extensions (`$('.foo').click(function(){})`), but they do the exact same so I'd expect the difference to be minimal, if anything.